# How to stop jackson timezone conversion and not apply local offset

Tags: java, json, datetime, jackson, jackson-databind

In my java dto i am converting json date ("dispOn": "11/28/2020",) to java.util.Date.since i am not sending any timezone jackson is taking UTC as default time zone but when desterilizing it is taking the offset of CST(My local time)as a result, date in my code(11/27/2020) is one day behind

import java.util.Date;

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")
private Date dispOn;
```

How can i get the same date sending in json into my code

Comment: Replace `java.util.Date` with `java.time.LocalDate`. --- Add dependency on `jackson-datatype-jsr310`, and call `mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())`, to make it work.

Comment: To elaborate, a `java.util.Date` is essentially a glorified `long` representing the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch. It's not very good at storing month/day/year information; that's what `LocalDate` is for.

Answer (score 0):

As Andreas mentioned in his comment, it is sufficient to change from Date to LocalDate.
For additional info, I used LocalDateTime to show you how the format should be configured. I'm also using Lombok's annotations on class-level for logging and getter/setter generation.
Keep in mind that LocalDate and LocalDateTime are only available since Java 8.

Below a complete example of a DTO in which I parse a JSON

```
@Slf4j
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) // optional annotation
public class MyMessage implements Deserializer<MyMessage> {

    @JsonProperty("EVENT_TIMESTAMP")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,
                pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    private LocalDateTime eventTimestamp;
    @JsonProperty("MESSAGE")
    private String message;

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
        Deserializer.super.configure(configs, isKey);
    }

    @Override
    public MyMessage deserialize(String s, byte[] bytes) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        MyMessage event = null;
        try {
            event = mapper
                    .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
                    .readValue(bytes, MyMessage.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Something went wrong during the deserialization of the MyMessage: {}", e.getMessage());
        }
        return event;
    }

    @Override
    public MyMessage deserialize(String message, Headers headers, byte[] data) {
        return Deserializer.super.deserialize(message, headers, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        Deserializer.super.close();
    }
```

And the JSON I'm sending:

```
{
"EVENT_TIMESTAMP": "2022-03-15T14:14:05.945",
"MESSAGE": "Test 123"
}
```